# Creating Custom WPF Controls in IronPython: a control made up out of standard controls

Tags: python, wpf, custom-controls, ironpython, composite-controls

I've looked at the other custom control creation questions on here, as well as other online resources, but I'm lost as to how to create a custom control that doesn't require a C# code-behind file. Since my project is pure IronPython, I don't know how I would integrate the C# code behind with it.

What I'm trying to do isn't even that complicated; no messy styling or render transformations or anything. I'm merely trying to create a composite control of a bunch of existing ones I have, so that I can add/remove these composite controls procedurally. For example, I have this GroupBox:

[image]

As you can see, it's just a GroupBox with a TextBox and a ComboBox in the Header, with its body populated by a UniformGrid containing some CheckBoxes. Here is the XAML:

```
<GroupBox Name="DO1">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">DO1</TextBlock>
            <ComboBox Name="DO1DeviceList" Margin="3 0 0 0" ItemsSource="{Binding DOtable}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="3W1L" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o1" IsChecked="{Binding o1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="3W3V" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o2" IsChecked="{Binding o2}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Ni" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o3" IsChecked="{Binding o3}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="2W1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o4" IsChecked="{Binding o4}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Vac2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o5" IsChecked="{Binding o5}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="3W4V" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o6" IsChecked="{Binding o6}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Cu" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o7" IsChecked="{Binding o7}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="3W2L" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox Name="DO1o8" IsChecked="{Binding o8}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </UniformGrid>
</GroupBox>
```

I've read about control compositing, grouping a bunch of controls into a single control. I'd like to make this whole GroupBox a single control I can add or remove procedurally. How can I accomplish this with IronPython?

Comment: Looks like the image you've included doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 1):

I still feel like there's a better way, so I'll leave this question open, but the way I ended up doing run-time addition of custom controls in IronPython is by simply placing the XAML in a seperate file, loading it with `XamlReader.Load()` and storing the return value in a new object. That object becomes the control, which can then be added to a `Grid`, `DockPanel`, or what have you. It took me a while to make the mental connection that I could use `XamlReader` to construct any control from XAML, not just `Window`s.

```
with File.OpenRead("MyControl.xaml") as xamlfile:
    newcontrol = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xamlfile)

ui.FindName("MyDockPanel").Children.Add(newcontrol)
```

The XAML file simply contains the above aforementioned `GroupBox` markup along with an `xmlns` attribute to establish the right namespace.

```
<GroupBox Name="DO1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <GroupBox.Header>
    ...
```